# XFS fs does not mount on boot but mounts ro ok from cli

Tags: centos7, xfs, fsck

I have a server with a LSI raid controller. The server shows two devices sda and sdb. sdb is not partitioned but has a xfs  fs formatted directly (i don't know why) into it. We decide to reboot it after 100+ days of working flawlessly to test a new startup script. When coming back online it drops into an emergency boot complaining that superblock not found. I did xfs_repair -n and it could not find a secondary superblock.  What is really strange is that if I mount it read-only in the console it mounts ok.

Comment: You should add more information like relevant line of */etc/fstab*, the exact commands and output you did with `xfs_repair` and also the relevant part of `dmesg` after running `xfs_repair`.

Answer (score 1):

After reading Thomas comment I an found error. I checked  fstab  and verify mounted fs. Both types were different. fstab had  type xfs but the filesystem was really ext4. so the error was in the fstab.